# Normalizer for padding a user's input

Tags: redux, padding, normalization, redux-form

i have an input field who accepts only numeric values.
This field must have a normalizer that autofill a user input with zeros. Also the length must not be greater than eight.
For example if i type 1 the field must be prefilled with 00000001. If i type 00000012.
Do you know how to achieve such an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your normalize function like:

```
const normalizer = (value) => String("00000000" + value).slice(-8);
```

this will convert input into a 8 digits length, 0-padded value.

Then you simply define your `Field` as

```
<Field name="number" component="input" type="number" normalize={normalizer} />
```

See working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nl9759rz)